# Methods dont show with Live soap web service consumption in ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I add the reference and all and then when i have to build up to getting the methods and then parsing values to the different atrributes i cant seem to get methods that i can pass variables too, all i can get is the attributes themselves which i cant parse values directly too.. i am new to soap web services and would like some assistance. the WSDL URL is https://secure.transunion.co.za/TUBureau118test/Consumer.asmx?WSDL and I have trying to do this with the HelloWorld method and the BureauPing, any of the two as an example to the way forward would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you added the reference as a WCF service under the namespace 'ServiceReference1':

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ws = new ServiceReference1.ConsumerSoapClient();
            string result = ws.HelloWorld();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am actually using a web form and I have a button that does the calling of the web service, but i cant seem to get the methods after creating the objects of the different classes that are available to me via the WSDL document

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Hello : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Transunion.ActiveRiskAddresses test = new Transunion.ActiveRiskAddresses();
        Transunion.ActiveRiskAddresses result = test.AddressLine1(txtCounterField.Text); 
    }

} problem is test.AddressLine

Comment: Are you able to create an instance of the 'ConsumerSoapClient' object?

Comment: No, I am unable to create the object. that is my initial problem, please look at the above code

Comment: AddressLine1 is a property, not a method, so you can't call it like 'test.AddressLine1(x)', but you can supply a value like 'test.AddressLine1 = "My address"'. In order to use the methods from the web service, you must first create an instance of 'Transunion.ConsumerSoapClient'.

Comment: According to the WSDL, the ActiveRiskAddresses are part of the BureauResponse object, which in turn is part of the several 'ProcessRequestTransxx' methods (xx being a number starting from 1). You can call these methods after instantiating the ConsumerSoapClient object.

Comment: created the consumer soap client and now it gets to working as i need it 2